# AngularJS reject a promise in success callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I'm using `$q` to check if two resources' queries have been resolved or not. Like this:

```
$q.all([
    ResourceA.get({}, function success(data) {
        console.log("got A");
    }).$promise,
    ResourceB.get({}, function success(data) {
        console.log('got B');
    }).$promise
]).then(function() {
    console.log("done");
});
```

The question is, the `data` I'm receiving in each of the `success` functions might not be what I want and I wanna check if that's the case then reject the correspondent promise. Like:

```
$q.all([
    ResourceA.get({}, function success(data) {
        if (data.key !== "secret") {
            // REJECT THE PROMISE
        }
    }).$promise,
    ResourceB.get({}, function success(data) {
        console.log('got B');
    }).$promise
]).then(function() {
    console.log("done");
});
```

Is this possible? How? Any better way?

Comment: you can add third promise and resolve or reject it

Comment: Don't use the `success` callback. Use `then`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually simpler than the comment suggests since promises chain. If you want to chain though - you need to do it with `then`:

```
$q.all([
    ResourceA.get({}).$promise.then(function(data){ // chain a then
        if (data.key !== "secret") return $q.reject("Invalid key");
        return data; // return same value if ok
    }),
    ResourceB.get({}, function success(data) {
        console.log('got B');
    }).$promise
]).then(function() {
    console.log("done");
});
```